# import hotmail contacts using asp.net

Tags: vb.net, api, email, contacts

i need to import `live`/`hotmail` contacts using asp.net. I have done gmail and yahoo. i looked at `opencontactsnet.dll` and it doesnt work for live. none of the contacts are retrieved from that dll. does anyone know anything specifically for hotmail contacts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems guys here forgot to answer you... :)

Please try to follow this Windows Live SDK: [Messenger connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff752317.aspx)

I think you have a way to fetch contacts. Maybe this is the correct approach!