# Importing Contacts from Hotmail

Tags: java

I  am  facing  problem  importing contact   from  hotmail .Actually  I want   to  use  the
http   to   fetch   the  contacts .But I am not getting  any  client side implementation 
for  fetching   contact  from hotmail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [import hotmail contacts using asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050016/import-hotmail-contacts-using-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand you, but you might want to check out [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which offers an API to do the web driving and interprete the webpages. Is that what you are looking for?